# this Bubble sort program gives me "array out of bound exception" can sombody help me to resolve this

Tags: java

```java
class Bubble {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int[] a={20, 22, 19, 45, 9};
        int temp;

        for (int i = 0; i <= a.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j <= a.length - 1; j++) {
                if (a[j] > a[j + 1]) {
                    temp = a[j];
                    a[j] = a[j + 1];
                    a[j + 1] = temp;
                }
            }
        }

        for (int i = 0; i < a.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(a[i] + "");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This is the time to start the debugger.

Comment: You're not being charged by the character in your code. People are more likely to be able to help you with your code if they can read it.

Comment: you're trying to get something out of an array, which is beyond the array. For example; you have an array that can hold 8 items and you're trying to get the 9th item. It probably has something to do with your for loop and the a[j+1]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: This program tries to access two elements outside the array.

Answer (score 0):

Please format your code correctly next time. It'll make it much easier to help you.

Your main problem is that in the nested loop that iterates over `j`, you compare `a[j]` with `a[j+1]`. Since the maximum range for `j` is `4` (size of array is `5`), at the last index you won't be able to compare `a[4]` with `a[5]` because `a[5]` does not exist. This is what gives the exception.

To fix this, you should make j iterate as such:

```
int j=0; j < a.length-2; j++
```

You don't have to process the last index since it does not have anything subsequent to be compared to.